# How to print server-side with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I am new to asp.net and to programming altogether. I have an asp.net mvc web app, that is hosted on Azure. Basically it is for a store where different salesmen make sales and enter the information on the site. I want that after each sale is saved that one computer that is attached to a printer to print invoice. the question is how can I achieve that with server-side printing. how can i get the server to talk to one computer, when it is hosted in the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create api method in your web app that return new orders, after that you need to create a sub programm that request your api method for orders from web app and send them to print. Run sub programm on customer machine with printer.

Comment: is there no simple way of doing this for example System.Drawing.Printing?

Comment: @abe Sure, but that will probably be running in a program on the machine you want to print from, not in the cloud. Which is why you need some sort of client application.

Comment: having windows server installed on client would make thing easier?

Comment: If you can reach your printer from your azure server, you can send order to print from server.

Comment: @abe whats system are installed it doesnt matter (mac os\ *nix\windows etc)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify your answer? By a sub program are you referring to a wcf service?

Comment: @abe, Console app will be enough, you can run it as a windows service